# Exchange to office365 migration creates Event(icalender) issue

Tags: php, exchange-server, office365, icalendar

Recently my organization shifted from hosted Exchange on Rackspace to Office365.

I had a working script to send events written in php so as events that can be accepted or rejected in Outlook 2010. However the migration seems to have broken the script. Insted of the event I now see an email message body filled with my iCalender details like below:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-fgdfg
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:abc
DTSTAMP:20150909T052235Z
DTSTART:20150908T040000Z
DTEND:20150908T060000Z
SUMMARY:abc
ORGANIZER;CN=name:mailto:namne@xx.com
DESCRIPTION:abc
LOCATION:asdasd
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

The Code for creating event and sending the email is as below:

```
$desc = 'abc';
$start = '20150908T0400';
$end = '20150908T0600';
$location = 'asdasd';
$message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-fgdfg
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:".$desc."
DTSTAMP:" . gmdate('Ymd').'T'. gmdate('His') . "Z
DTSTART:".$start."00Z
DTEND:".$end."00Z
SUMMARY:".$desc."
ORGANIZER;CN=".$organizer.":mailto:".$organizer_email."
DESCRIPTION:".$desc."
LOCATION:".$location."
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";
$headers .= $message;

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->CharSet = "utf8";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$mail->Port = xx; 
$mail->IsHTML(false);
$mail->Username = "name@xx.com";
$mail->Password = "pwd";
$mail->SetFrom("$organizer_email");
$mail->AddAddress($to,"xx");
$mail->Subject = "$desc";
$mail->Body = "$message";
$mail->AddCustomHeader($headers);
if(!$mail->Send())//Send mail
{
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
    echo "\n".$desc." message has been sent";
}
```

The only thing changed for Office365 mail is server name, port number and ssl to tls.

Any help is aprreciated.